# Proof explanation: If $a_n \leq c \text{ } \forall \text{ } n \in \mathbb{N}$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \leq c$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, cauchy-sequences

I have difficulties understanding this proof.

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a convergent sequence with $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$.

Prove: If $a_n \leq c \text{ } \forall \text{ } n \in \mathbb{N}$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then $a \leq c$.

**Proof:**

Suppose $a > c \Rightarrow a-c > 0$

Since $a_n \to a$ there exists $\forall \epsilon > 0$ an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ with $|a_n-a| < \epsilon  \text{ } \forall n > N,$ especially for $\epsilon = a-c$

$$\Rightarrow |a_n-a| < a-c \text{ } \forall n > N \\ \Leftrightarrow - (a-c) <  a_n -a < a-c \text{ } \forall n > N \\\Leftrightarrow c<a_n \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

I already have troubles understanding what is being asked for. For example, if we have $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and $c = 1$, is the statement implying that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0 \Rightarrow 0 < 1$?

As for the proof, I cannot visualize in my head what is meant with $|a_n -a| < a -c$ and how we get to $c < a_n$.

Comment: There seems to be some errors or typing errors in what you have written. Here is the idea of the proof. It's proof by contradiction so assume that $c < a$ and choose a $b$ such that $c < b < a$. Since the limit is $a$ all the elements of the sequence beyond certain $N$ must be bigger than $b$ which contradicts $a_n \leq c$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Rishi Thanks, I edited the post. I still don't understand. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Please understand that "Suppose $P\implies Q$" does **not** mean "Suppose $P;$ then $Q$ follows"!  For example, "Assume that $x=1\implies x>0$" is a redundant sentence because you're assuming a mathematical fact, whereas "Assume that $x=1$" (which implies that $x>0$) is indeed a potentially fruitful assumption.

Comment: @stepbysteptomathpro what does it mean by a sequence converging to a number? Once you understand that and the definition of convergence you will understand this proof. $a_n \to a$ means that no matter how close we go towards $a$, there is always an $N$ such that all the $a_n$ are closer to $a$ for $n > N$. For example consider the sequence $0.9$, $0.99$, $0.999 \ldots$. This obviously converges to $1$ but what does it mean in mathematical terms? Take any number $b < 1$ and this sequence will eventually go over $b$. Say $b = 0.999999999.....$(100 times) it will still go over that at some point.

Comment: So in your case if sequence converges to $a$ and $c < b < a$ then the sequence will eventually go over $b$ which contradicts the fact that $a_n \leq c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thin you have a typo when you say: **Suppose $a<c\implies a-c=0$**. The proof is by reductio ad absurdum, you assume that the result is false, that's it, $a>c$, so $a-c>0$ and you can take positive $\epsilon=a-c$ . With this assumption you end up having that for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$(that depends on the choosen $\epsilon$) we have that $a_n>c$ for $n>N$, but that contradicts our hypothesis, hence $a<c$

Comment: Can you give me an example for what the proof is actually implying?

Comment: Basically the statement is that if we have a bounded convergent sequence, the limit of the sequence is also bounded by the same bound. For example $a_n=\frac{n}{n+1}$ is bounded by $1$ and it's convergent, so the limit must be bounded by $1$

Answer (score 2):

Beware: $a>c$ implies $a-c>0$, not $c-a>0$ (you have a typo, easily fixable).

How do you show that $a\le c$, where $a$ and $c$ are arbitrary real numbers? You can prove that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, it holds that $a<c+\varepsilon$.

So, take $\varepsilon>0$. Then, by definition of convergence, there exists $N$ such that, for $n>N$, it holds that
$$
|a_n-a|<\varepsilon
$$
that implies
$$
a<a_n+\varepsilon
$$
Choose $n>N$. Then
$$
a<a_n+\varepsilon\le c+\varepsilon
$$
because, by assumption, $a_n\le c$. Therefore we have proved that $a<c+\varepsilon$ and we're done.

---

Your argument is good as well, but with some fixes. You find $N$ such that, for $n>N$, it holds that
$$
|a_n-a|<a-c
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
c-a<a_n-a<a-c
$$
and the left inequality is the same as $a_n>c$, which is false for every $n$, but should hold for all $n>N$. Contradiction.

---

Yes, using this result for $a_n=1/n$, you prove that $0\le 1$. That's true, isn't it?